# Improving build time with Gulp and Babel

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I'm trying to speed up the build time after adding `gulp-babel` to my build process...

At first I thought `gulp-cached` might help, but this resulted in the compiled file only containing those files that were most recently edited (I see now that's how `gulp-cached` works).

Without babel my build time was < 200ms.
With babel it's up to 1.5 seconds.
I sure would like to have it back down to 200ms...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use gulp-cached and gulp-remember. Only files that have changed will go through the pipeline and then gulp-remembers adds them all back in. :)

```
return gulp.src(array)                                                        
    .pipe(cached('babel is fun'))                                                      
    .pipe(babel())                                                           
    .pipe(remember('babel is fun'))                                                    
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dir));
```

Comment: This seriously improved build performance when post processing Typescript output as well!  I simply wrapped the babel-step - and repeated build cycles took half the time.  Thank you for this great tip!